# Must Kivy properties be used in all classes?

Tags: python, kivy

Classic common-sense programming says to separate the GUI code from the core processing.  I started this way in Kivy, but ran into a problem in my first-round prototype.

### deck.py

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.name = "%s %s" % (suit, value)
```

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from deck import Card

class CardDisplay(BoxLayout):

    card = ObjectProperty(Card("Default", 0))


class BoardDisplay(BoxLayout):
    board = [[Card("Player1", 1),
              Card("Player1", 2),
              Card("Player1", 3),
              Card("Player1", 4)],
             [Card("Player2", 1),
              Card("Player2", 2),
              Card("Player2", 3),
              Card("Player2", 4)]]

class GameApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ in ("__main__", "__android__"):
    GameApp().run()
```

### game.kv

```
BoardDisplay:
    orientation: "vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[0][0]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[0][1]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[0][2]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[0][3]

    BoxLayout:
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[1][0]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[1][1]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[1][2]
        CardDisplay:
            card: root.board[1][3]


<CardDisplay>:
    Label:
        text: root.card.name
```

Running this, I get an 8-card display as expected, but all of the cards are "Default 0".  I think this is because I am using root.card.name, which is not a StringProperty, but just an attribute of the card class.  However... what is the better way to do this?  Am I really supposed to inherit from Widget (or something like it) in every class that contains something I'll want to display (in this case, Card)?  Or is there a binding method I am failing to understand?  I read through the Kivy docs and could swear it mentioned a problem just like this, but I wasn't able to find the reference again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `root.card.name` isn't a `Property`, so when you assign it (`text: root.card.name`) Kivy doesn't know to bind to anything. Binding happens automatically in kv, but it's not perfect. So here's an easy fix:

```
<CardDisplay>:
    Label:
        text: root.card and root.card.name
```

The result of the expression `root.card and root.card.name` will be the value of `root.card.name`, assuming `root.card` is assigned. But when Kivy reads that assignment, it sees that you are using `root.card` and will bind appropriately.

The key to using properties is knowing when you want to be notified about updates. You don't need `root.card.name` to be a `StringProperty` unless you want to know when that property is updated. In other words, if you change the `Card` instance used by `CardDisplay`, then it will update the `Label`. However, if you were to just update the `name` attribute of a `Card`, the `Label` would **not** update.

However, this applies equally to the `board` attribute on `BoardDisplay`. Updating this attribute will not update the display, since `board` isn't a property. But Kivy can handle lists of lists and provide notifications on updates:

```
board1 = ListProperty([Card("Player1", i) for i in range(4)])
board2 = ListProperty([Card("Player2", i) for i in range(4)])
board = ReferenceListProperty(board1, board2)
```

This way you will get notifications all around.

Oh, one thing I forgot to mention: if you do need to use properties on a non-`Widget` (like `Card`), you can extend from `EventDispatcher` to get properties to work. Kivy isn't just a UI, it's a framework. It's ok to use Kivy in non-UI code. If you have used data binding in .NET, you can think of `Widget` as a `Control` or `UIElement` and `EventDispatcher` as `DependencyObject`.